# how to format number in wanted format- angular js

Tags: angularjs, numbers, angular-filters

I have number in this format 7873 and I need to convert it in this format 7'873.

The second format I have is 3564.55443 and I need to format it to 3564.5. For the second format I used number:1 filter, but it formatted it like 3,564.5, but I don't need the comma in the front.

Can someone help me do this ? I am using Angular 1.5.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may help.[number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) it format the numeric out put...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution may be to [create your own custom filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) and use them in combination with the native [angular number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).

```
app.filter('withTick', function () {
    return function(input) {
        return input.replace(/,/g, "'");
    };
});
```

Implementation `{{ myNumber | number | withTick }}` (using the Angular number filter first will format the number with commas), after which we  replace all the commas with `'`.

Note: the above assumes you want to put a `'` character wherever a comma would be. If you're after something else (like just putting a single `'` after the first character) you can manipulate and return the input as you would any javascript string.

Removing commas is similar: `{{ myNumber | number:1 | noComma }}` which will include the (rounded) single decimal, then you can make the `noComma` filter to replace all `,` with `''`.